# Once we've configured datasource in JBoss AS should we add the JDBCDriver to dependencies in our maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm working on a web project using maven, AppServer: `JBoss AS 7`. I'd like to clarify if we should add `JDBCDriver` into maven dependencies after I've configured my datasource configuration? I suspect it would be superflous, because JBoss AS is already used driver configured within the `module.xml` file as follows

```
<datasources>
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</connection-url>
         <driver>com.mysql</driver>
      <!-- something else -->
   </datasource>
<datasources>
<drivers>
  <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
  </driver>
</drivers>
```

, but I don't know for sure. Couldn't you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no need to add it in `pom.xml` because you have directly added `jdbcDriver.jar` for `JBossAS`. Adding `mysql-connector-java` in `pom.xml` will make sense if you would be using `jboss-as-maven-plugin` to deploy the `mysql datasource`

Comment: Just to be sure, the plugin is used to deploy an application to JBoss, is it?

Comment: @St.Antario You can use `jboss-as-maven-plugin` to deploy `mysql datasource` and then there is no need to add changes into `module.xml`